# Reactive UI cancel removing item from ReactiveList

Tags: c#, reactiveui

What is the best way to cancel item removing from `ReactiveList`?
I have:

```
ReactiveList<SomeObject> myList;
```

This list is subscribed in two way:

```
this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.myList.Count).Subscribe(_ => this.DoSomething());
myList.BeforeItemsRemoved.Subscribe(BeforeItemRemoved);
```

And I whant to check some condition in `BeforeItemRemoved` method, that can cancel removing this object from list, so how can I cancel item removing on `BeforeItemsRemoved`?

Comment: did you try throwing an exception? not a good answer I admit

Comment: I believe that result for this solution is to unexpectable to accept it

Comment: @kenny this list is binded to multiselect combobox as selected items, throwing caused that item was not removed from list but it was no longer selected on combobox anymore

Answer (score 2):

BeforeItemsRemoved is an observable triggered before the item is really removed from the list but you can not stop it from being removed. It's works the same way than INotifyPropertyChanging and INotifyPropertyChanged you get a trigger before the action and after.

You can probably extend ReactiveList to achieve what you need or save the item in BeforeItemsRemoved and add it again on ItemsRemoved trigger (more a workaround than a solution).